# Figure out which part of or statement matches condition?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a fundamental and basic python question. I searched in the google but I couldn't find the answer. I am wondering when I use `or` in `if condition` is there any way to see which part of `if` condition is correct in the following example.

I have list : `my= ['A','B','C']`

```
if 'S' in my or 'T' in my or 'C' in my:
    print('yes')     # now I wanna know which one is correct. the answer here is `C`
```

Note : I know I can use `for` loop over elements of `my`  to figure it out. I am wondering if there is a keycode for that or not.

Comment: You can't. Use separate conditions, or wrap the condition in a loop construct. A good choice might be something like `for x in ['S', 'T', 'C']: if x in my: ...`

Comment: What is the specific use-case for needing that? Are you trying to find which character to use later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both repeated code and `any` are already in other answers, I thought it would be worthwhile to give another angle as an example of a one-liner `if`:

```
print('S' if 'S' in my else 'T' if 'T' in my else 'C' if 'C' in my else 'Nothing')
```

Or if you're ok with loops, a one-liner can look like this:

```
print([char for char in 'STC' if char in my][0])  # Would throw IndexError if not found
```

Comment: can I write it? like : `f.write('S' if 'S' in my else 'T' if 'T' in my else 'C' if 'C' in my else 'Nothing')`. I have to write it in the file

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following use of `any`. It would be nice if you could write

```
# NameError on print(x)
if any(x in my for x in ['S', 'T', 'C']):
    print(x)
```

except `x` is only in scope for the generator expression. You can, however, use an assignment expression to capture the last assignment to `x` for use after `any` returns.

```
if any((witness := x) in my for x in ['S', 'T', 'C']):
    print(witness)
```

`witness` is repeatedly set to `x`; when a comparison finally succeeds, `any` stops making comparisons, so `witness` is left set to the last value checked.

Answer (score 1):

Repetitive walrus one:

```
if (x := 'S') in my or (x := 'T') in my or (x := 'C') in my:
    print('yes', x)
```

With your list it prints `yes C`.

I see chepner already posted a similar one. Mine has more code repetition, but has the advantage of being lazy, evaluating only as many expressions  as needed, until the first hit.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7fSViFa3VFdR90JiJ3VY7m4MtMUNCoUrGwV1IPVNRUy8xRyKxXyi2BiIVjEnGFiVlwKQFBQlJlXoqFemVqsrqNQofn/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

You have to isolate each expression so you can test it later:

```py
my = ['A','B','C']

S = 'S' in my
T = 'T' in my
C = 'C' in my
if S or T or C:
    # Now examine S, T and C separately
    print('yes')
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be any different than what was asked since OP could still check `in` within the `if` body

Comment: True, but that could be expensive to repeat all the tests if `my` is very large.